# How does ng-repeat parse the source expression?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

`[...Array(4).keys()]` is valid javascript (ES6) for generating `[0,1,2,3]`.

`<span ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3]">` works as expected in angularJS but NOT `<span ng-repeat="i in [...Array(4).keys()]">`.

Nor does `<span ng-repeat="i in $eval('[...Array(4).keys()]')">`.

So how is the angular engine parsing the expression such that former works but not the latter?

FWIW, the exception starts as:

> ````
>  ```
> angular.js:9037 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$parse/syntax?p0=.&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=2&p3=%5B...Array(4).keys()%5D&p4=...Array(4).keys()%5D
>     at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:6:453
>     at Ya.throwError (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:152:398)
> ...
> ````

```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions). If you want to run more complex JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method and call the method from your view.  Then it will be easier to understand, debug, test, and maintain.

Comment: Yes I read that and I understand there are other ways of doing it, but I would like to understand why the $eval(...) doesn't work in particular, and if there is a way to harness the full capabilities of JS within AngularJS expressions.

Comment: $eval() takes an expression as argument, which is parsed the same way, and thus follows the same rules as all the other angular expressions. Angular expressions look like JS expressions, but they're not. You can only use what AngularJS supports/allows.